# Ipython Have all outputs to stdout be included in history

Tags: ipython, stdout, ipython-magic

Is there a way to have print statements be considered a valid output in python so that they appear in `%history -o`.

The needs is to create doc-tests from a session, however only returns are added to the history. Writes to stdout and err are not. However in doc-test the writes to stdout are used to match the test-case.